# Validar CPF e CNPJ

Tags: angular, validator

Alguém sabe de algum validador de CPF e CNPJ pra Angular 2?
Vi um *package* para Angular 1 como diretivas, a implementação é a mesma?

[link do pacote](https://github.com/gil/ng-cpf-cnpj)

Comment: Consegui criar um código para validação de CNPJ no angular 2, podem reabrir a pergunta pra eu postar?